# Synch the multiple databases data into one database

Tags: database, asynchronous, transform, etl

We have databases like oracle, sql server, postgres and  looking to synch the data like full/delta load into one database. Can you suggest some tool to do this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [SSMA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/sql-server-migration-assistant?view=sql-server-ver15) can do that.

Migration Sources allowed are:

- SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access
- SQL Server Migration Assistant for DB2
- SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL
- SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle
- SQL Server Migration Assistant for SAP ASE

But the destination will always be SQL Server.

Once your databases are all SQL Server I suggest you to merge them all together dividing them by schema.

Is a very primitive way to work but is the only I know.